# Create correlation table for large number of variables

Tags: r

Let say I want to create 1000 variables with pre-specified correlations.

I would start by creating a correlation matrix of the following form:

```
a<-matrix(c(1,.8,.8,.8,1,.8,.8,.8,1),3)
```

Obviously this can be hand-coded for 3 variables but how can I easily create the same thing for 1000 variables? each of the correlations should be the same (i.e. .8)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
example <- matrix(rep(0.8,25),5,5)
```

Or as @Vincent pointed out, `matrix(0.8,5,5)` is much better.

```
diag(example) <- 1

> example
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1.0  0.8  0.8  0.8  0.8
[2,]  0.8  1.0  0.8  0.8  0.8
[3,]  0.8  0.8  1.0  0.8  0.8
[4,]  0.8  0.8  0.8  1.0  0.8
[5,]  0.8  0.8  0.8  0.8  1.0
```

Then you can just scale it up to as large as you need. In your case:

```
mat2 <- matrix(0.8,1000,1000)
```

Comment: You can write the first line even more concisely: `example <- matrix(.8,5,5)`.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd Thanks. I just woke up.

Comment: +1 (nb, you forgot the `diag(mat2) <- 1` statement for the OP's case)

Comment: @gung I just thought it would be needlessly redundant.